# HTML/JQuery: Disable span / button click (greying it out and disable click)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-5

I have two spans that display certain information upon click, and I was unsure how I can grey out the spans to look like a disabled button when the other one is clicked. My code is below. I thought I could do something like `$("#toggle-odd").attr("disabled", true")` or `$("toggle-odd").unbind("click")` but neither seemed to give me the desired result.

```js
$("document").ready(function(){
    $("#odd").hide();
    $("#even").hide();
});

$("#toggle-odd").click(function(){
    $("#even").hide();
    $("#odd").toggle();
});

$("#toggle-even").click(function(){
    $("#odd").hide();
    $("#even").toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- CSS only -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<span class="btn btn-contrast" style="background-color: green" href="#" id="toggle-odd"> Show Odd Objects </span>
<span class="btn btn-contrast" style="background-color: red" href="#" id="toggle-even"> Show Even Objects </span>

<p id="odd">
  Odd
</p>

<p id="even">
 Even
</p>
```

Comment: Have you tried it with some CSS? So adding removing specific classes?

Comment: As you're using bootstrap 5, adding the "disabled" attribute should suffice.   https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/buttons/#disabled-state  *but* it probably only works on an *actual* `button`, not a `span`

Comment: However... a quick test (deleted answer) and re-reading the link above shows that adding `disabled` *also* disable's all `pointer-events` so you can't click the "disabled" button - so it depends on which way round you want your "disabled effect" to be applied.   You could also look in the bootstrap css to find which colours / effects it applies and copy them, leaving out the bit that disables pointer-events.

Comment: I'm using bootstrap 4 I believe, and I was having the spans in my code because the buttons, on click wouldn't display the text

Comment: Your snippet has `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2`  5.0.2

Comment: You can't achieve this on spans. You should change it to a button or another type of html control or just play with the colors in CSS.  Also for functionality use $("span").css("pointer-events", "none"); and back than $("span").css("pointer-events", "auto");

Comment: I just used the one from bootstrap that's my bad, I am using bootstrap 4 in my code

Comment: Thanks @DA I'll give it a go

Comment: Looks to be the same: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/buttons/#disabled-state

Comment: @freedomn-m I was just writing the same answer as you - I think this is the logic they want though: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/g5x74bat/

Comment: *the buttons wouldn't display the text* - make sure your button is `<button type='button'` so you're not POSTing any `form`.

Comment: Thanks everyone, got it working :) Appreciate the help

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan seems clunky that you have to turn one off to turn the other one on, but at least you're not stuck unable to click anything! :).  I added a 2nd snippet which allows toggle - but it's grey for selected, which seems the wrong way around to me.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure what the actual intended behaviour is, which is why I didn't post the answer

Comment: I only did it as an answer with immediate delete so I could use the snippet editor :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The span tag is made to display text. Here you should use buttons. If you want to disable the other button "graphically", just add a class ( I named it `disabled`). If you want to really disable it, add `$("#your-button").attr("disabled","disabled");`

In the following example I made sure that we can reactivate a button but if you want to keep it deactivated, you just have to extract the code of the first condition.

```js
$("document").ready(function(){
    $("#odd").hide();
    $("#even").hide();
});

$("#toggle-odd").click(function(){
    if($("#odd").css("display") == "none"){
      $("#toggle-even").attr("disabled","disabled");
      $("#toggle-even").addClass("disabled");
    }else{
      $("#toggle-even").removeAttr("disabled");
      $("#toggle-even").removeClass("disabled");
    }
    
    $("#even").hide();
    $("#odd").toggle();
});

$("#toggle-even").click(function(){
    if($("#even").css("display") == "none"){
      $("#toggle-odd").attr("disabled","disabled");
      $("#toggle-odd").addClass("disabled");
    }else{
      $("#toggle-odd").removeAttr("disabled");
      $("#toggle-odd").removeClass("disabled");
    }
    
    $("#odd").hide();
    $("#even").toggle();
});
```

```css
.disabled{
background-color: grey;
}

#toggle-odd{
  background-color: green
}

#toggle-even{
  background-color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- CSS only -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<button class="btn btn-contrast" id="toggle-odd"> Show Odd Objects </button>
<button class="btn btn-contrast" id="toggle-even"> Show Even Objects </button>

<p id="odd">
  Odd
</p>

<p id="even">
 Even
</p>
```